# Is this the right way of contract the definitoin of uniform convergence? (sequence of functions)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, functions

Let $ f_{n}=x^{n},I=[0,1] $. Prove that the sequence does not converge uniformly to any function.

So here's what I tried:

First notice that the sequence pointwise converge to the function :

$ f\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
0 & 0\leq x<1\\
1 & x=1
\end{cases} $

And thus if the sequence uniformly converge to some function $ g $ , then $ g $ have to be equal to $ f $. So its enough to show that the sequence does not uniformly converge to $ f $.

Now Im not sure with my claims here:
In order to contradict the definition, its enough to find specific $ \varepsilon > 0 $ such that for any $ N \in \mathbb{N} $ we will be able to find $ x\in I $ and $ n>N $ such that $ |f_{n}\left(x\right)-f\left(x\right)|\geq\varepsilon $.

Consider $ \varepsilon=\frac{1}{2} $ and let $ N $ be some natural number.

So if we'll take $ x_{0}=\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{\frac{1}{N+1}},n_{0}=N+1 $ we'll get:

$ |f_{N+1}\left(x_{0}\right)-f\left(x_{0}\right)|=\frac{3}{4}>\frac{1}{2} $.

Is this proof is correct or maybe I used the definitions wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's too complicated, sorry! If the convergence of a sequence of continuous functions is uniform on a compact set like $[0,1]$, the limiting function is continuous, too. Now your $f$ has a jump at $x=1$, so...

Comment: @ProfessorVector we haven’t learned any theorems yet. Had to use the definitions directly